# check if an email id exists in the AdminDirectory.Users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is there way to check if an email id exists in the AdminDirectory.Users or not? I know that https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get retrieves all the users, is there a query like `exists`(from sql) in Google apps script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `.get()` function is used to get an individual user.

To test is the user existis or not you can use `.get()` in a `try catch`

This function will return `true` if the user exists and `false` if not.

```
function lookupUser(email){
   var isUser
   try{
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email); 
      isUser = true;
  } catch (e){
      isUser = false;
 }
 return isUser;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @James, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If we base the methods in Directory API, there's [Users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) which has a 'query' property. The valid queries you can perform are found in [Search for users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) and sure enough there's an 'email' value.

Play around with that and try it in Apps Script's [List all users](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users).